# Image width: auto in block with position: absolute

Tags: css, google-chrome

Browser: google-chrome >43.x

If I resise height of window which contains:

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
}
div img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5ohw433s/

Then  square image become rectangle;

Switching height of image I can restore it, but it looks ugly and not complete solve the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/5ohw433s/1/

Other solution is to set `height: 900vh` and `max-height: 100%`

http://jsfiddle.net/5ohw433s/2/

but it still have problem, because if I resize parent block (by `:hover`)

http://jsfiddle.net/5ohw433s/3/

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: top 0.1s;
}
div:hover {
  top: 50px;
}
div img {
  max-height: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
</div>
```

it fails again.

Is there any good solution for the problem ?

Comment: the problem is that image not keep aspect ratio in some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your image display as `block` should working. Check the [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ohw433s/5/).